# How to disable Tkinter Combox while app is running?

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I want to disable a Combobox based on a selected value of another Combobox, my code is not working, the ComboBox still active, how to fixt it?

```
def update(event):
   F01 = ttk.Combobox(window, width = 20, state="disabled",values="option1","option2","option3")
   print("Disable F01")


window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Channel Configuration')
window.geometry('1200x800')

F01 = ttk.Combobox(window, width = 20, state="readonly". values="option1","option2","option3")
F01.grid(column = 2, row = 5)
F01.set("option1")
F02 = ttk.Combobox(window, width = 20, state="readonly", values="option1","option2","option3")
F02.grid(column = 3, row = 5)
F02.set("option1")

F02.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", update)    

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Use `F01.config(state="disabled")` instead of creating a new `ttk.Combobox`.

Answer (score 0):

You have one problem in your `update()` function, it won't update the F01 you want, it will create a new one and will be destroyed after you exit the function. to solve this you need to declare you are using the global F01:

```
global F01
```

Write this as the first line in the function.
also, you don't have to redo the whole ComboBox, you can also do:

```
F01.config(state="disabled")
```

Comment: No problem :) Just accept my answer so I will get the reward please ;)